# I have a list of bytes and I want a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, readlines

I want to take the first line of a file opened from an url, search for a specific string and then split that string.

```
    request=urllib.request.Request(url)
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    input_file=response.readlines()
    for l in input_file:
        if "target" in l:
           dum, stat = l.split(":")
           stat = stat.strip()
```

I expect to get a stat="StationX"
instead I get

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

because input_file is a list of type bytes instead of  type strings.
I don't know how to either bring input_file in as strings (I thought thats what readlines() vs read() did?) or convert the list of type bytes to a list of type stings.

Comment: The [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) package in PyPI could be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

The `urllib.request` package has a little nuance to it as highlighted below. One might expected the return type of `.read()` to be a string but it's actually raw bytes that you have to decode.

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> req = urllib.request.Request("http://www.voidspace.org.uk")
>>> res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> raw_contents = res.read()
>>> type(raw_contents)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> page = raw_contents.decode()
>>> type(page)
<class 'str'>
```

Now in your case

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
raw_lines = response.readlines()
for raw_line raw_lines:
    line = raw_line.decode()
    if "target" in line:
       dum, stat = l.split(":")
       stat = stat.strip()
```

Alternatively,

```
for line in map(lambda x: x.decode(), raw_lines):
    # etc
```

Comment: this makes a string out of every character in the file not a string for each line in the file.